# Template Specialization with External Errors

Tags: c++, templates

When I attempted to specialize one of my template functions, Visual Studio threw me an external error, including an error for a function that was not specialized.

The three errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall linearList<class FriendToken>::reverse(void)" (?reverse@?$linearList@VFriendToken@@@@UAEXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall linearList<class FriendToken>::print(void)" (?print@?$linearList@VFriendToken@@@@UAEXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall linearList<class FriendToken>::insertionSort(void)" (?insertionSort@?$linearList@VFriendToken@@@@UAEXXZ)
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
template<class T>
class arrayList : public linearList<T> 
{
public:
    //other methods
    void reverse();
    void print();
    void insertionSort();
};


template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::reverse()
{
            //method body
}
template<>
void arrayList<FriendToken>::insertionSort()
{
            //method body
}
template<>
void arrayList<FriendToken>::print()
{
            //method body
}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::insertionSort(){}
template<class T>
void arrayList<T>::print(){}
```

Comment: By any chance, aren't your member function definitions in a `.cpp` file?

Comment: Currently, all of the member functions are defined in the `.h` file.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's about *partial* specialization though

Comment: @AndyProwl, I think the answer to the OPs is there somewhere. (Than again I may have read it elsewhere and forgot).

Comment: Are all these functions declared before you attempt to call any of them?  ...  Never mind, I think @PorkyBrain spotted it.  The linker errors are complaining about a different class than the definitions shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shows specializations of the **arrayList** member functions which I assume are supposed to be overriding their virtual equivalants in **linearList**. The linker is saying it cant find the virtual members in the class **linearList** which is not included in your example.

```
virtual void __thiscall linearList<class FriendToken>::reverse(void)
```

If I add a definition of linearList like this the linker is quiet (on MSVC2010, I also added a empty FriendToken class to make things work).

```
template<typename T>
class linearList
{
public:
    virtual void reverse() = 0;    //pure virtual
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual void insertionSort() = 0;
};
```

If this is not your problem please post the code for linearList and I will update my answer as that is surely the source of your problem.

If needed for reference here is how I used the function reverse to test:

```
arrayList<FriendToken> a;
static_cast<linearList<FriendToken>&>(a).reverse();
```

Comment: I did have the virtual methods declared in linearList already. However, appending `=0` seems to fix it.

Comment: yes in retrospect I could have known that too, if the function wasn't declared the compiler would have given a different error.